# Getting "java.lang.StackOverflowError" while clicking the "Manage plugin" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm getting "java.lang.StackOverflowError" while clicking the "Manage plugin" in Jenkins version 1.589.

I'm getting the below error in "Updates" and "Available" tab only.

Please help me solve the issues.

Thanks&Regards,
 Sangeetha

[image]

Comment: Hi - Please help me to solve the issues- Sangeetha

Comment: Hi - Whether I need to upgrade the Jenkins?  -Sangeetha